# update all NULL fields MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'd like to update all NULL fields in one table to 0. Of course

```
UPDATE mytable SET firstcol=0 WHERE firstcol IS NULL
```

would do the job. But I wonder if there´s a smarter solution than just c&p this line for every column.

Comment: Out of curiosity how many columns you have that you need to change from null to 0 or w/e ehhe :)

Comment: It´s just curiosity. In this particular case, I would not need anything because it´s just 5 or 6 cols. But other tables i work with easily got 60 columns. That´s why I´d like to know how to do it in such a scenario too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you just `ALTER` the columns to `NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`?

You can do this in a single statement, as per [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

> You can issue multiple ADD, ALTER, DROP, and CHANGE clauses in a single ALTER TABLE statement, separated by commas. This is a MySQL extension to standard SQL, which allows only one of each clause per ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: Hmm, the table is created with a create table mytable AS SELECT ... statement that contains cases. Somehow i was not able to set default values there. That´s why I ended up with the NULL values. If I alter that table i´d have to do it for every column separately which is exactly what I am trying to prevent.

Comment: thx, obviously i did not know about this fact. Still, I wonder if i have to list all the columns in such an ALTER statement. I just want to do it for the whole table, because if I had 60 columns, it would ugly to list em all – no matter if in one or multiple statements.

Comment: @ran2: Yes, you have to list them all.

Comment: thanks Piskvor, good to know that. probably I am just a little spoiled by the functionality of R that allows to run functions on every column of a table.

Answer (score 16):

You could do this - repeat as necessary for each column:

```
UPDATE `table1`  SET
    `col1` = IFNULL(col1, 0),
    `col2` = IFNULL(col2, 0);
```

Example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `col1` int(10) unsigned,
  `col2` int(10) unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES
(1,    1, NULL),
(2, NULL, NULL),
(3,    2, NULL),
(4, NULL, NULL),
(5,    3,    4),
(6,    5,    6),
(7,    7, NULL);

UPDATE `table1`  SET
    `col1` = IFNULL(col1, 0),
    `col2` = IFNULL(col2, 0);

SELECT * FROM `table1`;

+----+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    0 |
|  2 |    0 |    0 |
|  3 |    2 |    0 |
|  4 |    0 |    0 |
|  5 |    3 |    4 |
|  6 |    5 |    6 |
|  7 |    7 |    0 |
+----+------+------+
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to alter the table structure by changing columns so that they no longer accept nulls, you could do it with a stored procedure.  The following stored procedure queries the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/columns-table.html) for information about columns in a given database table.  From that information, it builds up a prepared statement which is then used to alter the table structure.  You may need to tweak it to suit your exact requirements - at the moment, it looks for `INT` columns which do not have `NOT NULL` set:

```
delimiter //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS no_nulls//
CREATE PROCEDURE `no_nulls` (IN param_schema CHAR(255), IN param_table CHAR(255))
BEGIN

    SET @alter_cmd = (SELECT CONCAT(
        'ALTER TABLE ',
        param_table,
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            ' MODIFY COLUMN ',
            `column_name`, ' ',
            `column_type`,
            ' NOT NULL'
            SEPARATOR ', ')
        ) AS `sql_cmd`
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE `table_schema` = param_schema
    AND `table_name` = param_table
    AND LCASE(`data_type`) = 'int'
    AND LCASE(`is_nullable`) = 'yes');

    IF NOT ISNULL(@alter_cmd) THEN
        SELECT @alter_cmd;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @alter_cmd;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;

END//
delimiter ;
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`table1` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `col1` int(10) unsigned,
  `col2` int(10) unsigned,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CALL no_nulls('test', 'table1');
    +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @alter_cmd                                                                                                     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE table1 MODIFY COLUMN col1 int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  MODIFY COLUMN col2 int(10) unsigned NOT NULL |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

SHOW CREATE TABLE `test`.`table1`;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `col1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `col2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The following line displays the command that is to be executed, and may be removed from the stored procedure if necessary:

```
SELECT @alter_cmd;
```

Comment: i used just `UPDATE test SET userID = IFNULL(userId, 1);` and it worked

Answer (score 5):

You may want to alter your columns to `NOT NULL`.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY COLUMN your_field INT NOT NULL;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE nulltable (id INT);

INSERT INTO nulltable VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO nulltable VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO nulltable VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO nulltable VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO nulltable VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO nulltable VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO nulltable VALUES (5);
```

Result:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM nulltable;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
|    5 |
+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE nulltable MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL;
Query OK, 7 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.08 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 3

mysql> SELECT * FROM nulltable;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  0 |
|  0 |
|  0 |
|  5 |
+----+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: ran2 may want to do that in the long run, but that shouldn't update rows that already exist. At least, I hope it doesn't update rows that already exist.

Comment: @Brian: It does :) ... (I think unless running in strict mode.)

Comment: Yes, this works. Note that you may receive the rather generic 'DATA TRUNCATED' warning, but nothing has really been truncated - it's just one of those [slightly misleading error messages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-24-11-1-1).

Comment: @Brian Hooper: Other than a possible slight concern over MySQL not issuing a warning prior to making the change, this makes sense. NULL is ["a missing unknown value"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html). When the column is changed to disallow null values, something has to go in their place.

Answer (score 2):

Not without an intermediate technology or cursor. You could use `DESCRIBE mytable;` to get the column names and loop over them to build your `UPDATE` queries.

So it is possible. But by the time it took you to write that, you probably just could have copy and pasted ;)

Comment: I must admit, either I don´t get the answers or just posted badly. However, what Jason says was what I felt. I just wonder if there is a solution but a loop. I just did not need loops in SQL so far and thus have no experience :)

Comment: IMO, this is a trivial thing. Just run your statements by copy and paste. I do agree with the others though. If you started from scratch, you could have added a `DEFAULT 0` to your columns.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

```
UPDATE `results`  SET
    column1  = IFNULL(column1,0),
    column2  = IFNULL(column2,'');
```

This is mike's answer but without the quotes for columns on the left !

**Note:** If you are trying to set your values '0' instead of an empty string if a column's datatype is **int**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is; any statement that worked on rows that didn't satisfy the where clause would update rows you didn't intent to update. Jason's answer is correct, but, I think, a bit unsafe, unless you are really sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

*ALTER TABLE `dataBaseName`.`tableName` 
ADD COLUMN `columnX` INT(20) NULL DEFAULT 1 AFTER `columnY`;*

**It does the following**

1. adds a new column columnX after columnY.
2. sets its value to default 1 throughout the column columnX

---

```
           columnY             columnX 

         | cellValueA     |     1       |        
         | cellValueB     |     1       |
         | cellValueC     |     1       |
         | cellValueD     |     1       |
```